# Alter output of ddply

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Is it possible to alter the output of ddply? I wondered if was possible to present the unique results for a subset on ONE row instead of giving each result a new row. E.g.

```
ID   Season  Year
5074 Summer 2008
5074 Summer 2009
5074 Winter 2008
5074 Winter 2009
5074 Winter 2010
```

Into...

```
ID   Season  Year  
5074 Summer  2008,2009  
5074 Winter  2008,2009,2010
```

I often use ddply to manually diagnose the results of for-loops etc, and presenting the results like this would reduce the length of the output and making the check go much faster.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First load in the data

```
dd = read.table(textConnection("ID   Season  Year
5074 Summer 2008
5074 Summer 2009
5074 Winter 2008
5074 Winter 2009
5074 Winter 2010"), header=TRUE)
```

then just use `ddply` as normal, splitting by `ID` and `Season`

```
ddply(dd, .(ID, Season), summarise, Year=paste(Year, collapse=","))
```

We use the `collapse` argument in `paste` to return a single character. Since you want to use this as a check, it might be worth using `sort` on `Year`, i.e.

```
paste(sort(Year), collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID Season Year
 5074 Summer 2008
 5074 Summer 2009
 5074 Winter 2008
 5074 Winter 2009
 5074 Winter 2010", header = TRUE)
```

The output can be transformed using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Year ~ ID + Season, data = dat, paste)
#    ID Season             Year
#1 5074 Summer       2008, 2009
#2 5074 Winter 2008, 2009, 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect fit for the new *nice* printing of lists in `data.table` version 1.8.2

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dd)
DT[,list(Year = list(Year)), by = list(ID, Season)]
##     ID Season           Year
## 1: 5074 Summer      2008,2009
## 2: 5074 Winter 2008,2009,2010
```

The good thing about the results in this format is the fact that it is just the printing that is affected, you can still access the results without any string splitting

```
DT[(ID==5074)&(Season == 'Summer'), Year]
## [1] 2008 2009
DT[(ID==5074)&(Season == 'Winter'), Year]
## [1] 2008 2009 2010
```